# How to transform a binary QP into an MILP?

Tags: linearization, nonlinear-programming, convex-optimization, binary-variable, quadratic-programming

I have a binary quadratic problem with objective ${\bf{x}}^T{\bf{Qx}}+{\bf{c}}^T{\bf{x}}$

subject to

${\bf{A}}{\bf{x}}\le{\bf{b}}$

${\bf{A}}_{eq}{\bf{x}}={\bf{b}}_{eq}$.

here ${\bf{x}}$ is binary.

From https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7015136566801-Binary-Quadratic-Programming, we know that
we can transform this binary QP into a binary linear problem.

For my QP problem, then what will be objective function for the binary linear problem?

is it

$\sum{\bf{Qy}}+{\bf{c}}^T{\bf{y}}$?

where ${\bf{y}}$ is new variable for linearizing the multiplication of binary variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simplicity, lets assume $Q$ is a $2$ dimensional matrix:
$$
x^TQx = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} \\
q_{12} & q_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
=q_{11}x_1^2+q_{22}x_2^2+2q_{12}x_1x_2
$$

So your objective function looks like:
$$
q_{11}x_1^2+q_{22}x_2^2+2q_{12}x_1x_2 +c_1x_1 +c_2x_2
$$

Since $x_i$ are binaries, you can simplify to:
$$
q_{11}x_1+q_{22}x_2+2q_{12}x_1x_2 +c_1x_1 +c_2x_2
= (q_{11}+c_1)x_1 + (q_{22}+c_2)x_2 + 2q_{12}x_1x_2
$$

The last step is to use the linearization trick described in the link your provided for $x_1x_2$:

$$
(q_{11}+c_1)x_1 + (q_{22}+c_2)x_2 + 2q_{12}z_{12}
$$

with
\begin{align}
z_{12} &\le x_1 \\
z_{12} &\le x_2 \\
z_{12} &\ge x_1 +x_2-1
\end{align}

More generally, the objective function can be written as follows:
$$
\sum_i(q_{ii}+c_i)x_i + \sum_{i,j|i<j} 2q_{ij}z_{ij}
$$

Comment: would you please explain. Where does $Q$ go? What is $c_{i,j}$ as we have only $c_i$? What are $a_i$, $b_i$ here?

Comment: I have detailed the values of $Q$ in the 2-dimensional case.

Comment: Really nice! Please not that we may not have $q_{1,2}=q_{2,1}$. Would you please provide a more generalized and compact form for the objective function.

Comment: it would be surprising that matrix is not symmetric ($q_{12} \neq q_{21}$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming. I have added the generalized form for the objective function.

Comment: thanks a lot. For the second term in the objective, both I and j range from 1 to 2 (according to this example)? Or its I ranges from 1 to 2, and j>i.

Comment: yes you are right, $j>i$.